# Chronos insufficient resources warning

Tags: mesos, mesos-chronos

I'm trying to run Chronos on Mesos, but all my jobs are stuck in a `queueing` state.

`systemctl status chronos -l` shows:

```
Mar 20 20:21:08 core-mq3 chronos[17940]: [2017-03-20 20:21:08,985] WARN Insufficient resources remaining for task 'ct:1490040556081:0:JobName:', will append to queue. (Needed: [cpus: 0.5 mem: 256.0 disk: 256.0], Found: [cpus: 1.8 mem: 11034.0 disk: 60398.8,cpus: 2.0 mem: 6542.0 disk: 60399.0]) (org.apache.mesos.chronos.scheduler.mesos.MesosJobFramework:155)
```

So, it is refusing the offers even though all the resources are more than required.

Comment: Are constraints, roles and user available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a red herring. There was a constraint that the agent did not fulfill, which is why it couldn't run the task.
Running `curl GET <chronos>/scheduler/jobs/search?name=<job>` gave me all the details of the job, which I used to verify that the constraint was not being fulfilled.